# jquery autocomplete not picking dynamic data

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete, asp.net-web-api2

I am using following code and it always picks up hard coded data defined in `availableTags`. If I dynamically load data from C# WebApi, it still picks up old data i.e. ActionScript and AppleScript.

As you can see I am printing Before and After values and they both are working correctly i.e. as I can see it assigns new data to `availableTags` but autocomplete still works on old data. Is there a limit on how many items can I define in `availableTags`? Because dynamically it is getting 504 items from my code so may be this is the issue?

What am I doing wrong?

```
<input id="tags">

<script>
var availableTags =
[
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript"
];

$("#tags").autocomplete
({
    source: availableTags
});

$.getJSON("MyController/GetAllTags")
    .done(function (data)
    {
        alert("Before="+ availableTags);
        availableTags = data;
        alert("After="+ availableTags);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<input id="tags">

<script>
var availableTags =
[
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript"
];

$("#tags").autocomplete
({
    source: availableTags
});

$.getJSON("MyController/GetAllTags")
    .done(function (data)
    {
        $("#tag").autocomplete('option', 'source', data)
    });
</script>
```

**Edit 1: Updating Code**